# How do I count this piece?

Tags: guitar, theory, notation, practice, metronomes

I'm only used to standard groupings of notes (like triplets, sixteenth notes, sixteenth note triplets in 4/4) but I don't know how to read/interpret n-lets such as the ones below. 
[image]

How would I count these groupings to a metronome? What is the correct way to interpret groupings such as these? Note: Time signature for this is 12/8.

Comment: That sounds like a dupe of this: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/62667/how-are-very-long-tuplets-in-romantic-music-played-in-practice ...

Answer (score 1):

This will not be expected to be played in exact measure. Get a metronome and work out which beat each new run/phrase begins and then play all the notes in that 'run' before the next phrase is due to begin and you will automatically be playing in time.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a bit of 'widdley'.  Don't worry about precise counting.  Get the notes in, with impressive speed and attitude!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you actually do want to count that and play it accurately, you'll need to divide the count up. The 10-plet in the start of your example could for example be split into a 6+4 count, from looking at what you play there, or even 2+2+2+4.
Also if you have no experience with quintuplets, septuplets and so on, learn those first to get a feel for larger tuplets.